# Home and End keys don't work in putty + vim + xterm

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, putty

I'm using putty to ssh to Ubuntu with `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Inside vim, the home and end keys are not working properly. "`Home`" key makes vim enter in "`Insert`" mode and put a '`w`' character. Similarly "`End`" key makes vim enter in "`Insert`" mode before putting a '`q`' character.

The keys work fine outside vim. Home and End key puts the cursor at the beginning of the line or end of the line.

Also, this does not happen when I log in with `TERM=linux` set. Home and End keys inside vim function properly then.

Comment: This type of problem almost invariably comes down to the escape sequences being sent for various special keys. Check to make sure `$TERM` on the host you are connecting to corresponds to the settings in your PuTTY connection profile.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's the same "xterm-256color" in both putty configuration as well in the host. Same behavior with xterm.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I also tried editing escape sequences both by editing the terminfo file, compiling and exposing $TERMINFO variable. And also via editing /etc/vim/vimrc file and setting the proper values for both Home and End keys. No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally. After hours of scouring the internet I stumbled upon something which I should've done much earlier.

Fixed it by checking `"Disable application keypad mode`" inside `Terminal` -> `Features` in PuTTY configuration. Answering it now for anyone who faces this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `export TERM=putty-256color` solved my case for Ubuntu 20 with Putty.

Source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4809

Answer (score 0):

I got this behavior when I changed to screen-256color or tmux-256color, so I didn't want to change my terminfo.

If you like me are happy with your TERM setting you can also do a quick fix to reconfigure  and  as follows:

```
:set <Home>=<press Ctrl-V><press Home>
:set <End>=<press Ctrl-V><press End>
```

Above `set <Home>=` is a literal text you input, while the rest is what you press on your keyboard. Pressing `Ctrl-V`+`Key` adds the literal characters that result from pressing a key.

Trial and then add the above commands to your .vimrc to make the change permanent. You can also test the TERM variable:

```
if $TERM =~ '\v^(screen|tmux).*'
  set <Home>=^[OH
  set <End>=^[OF
endif
```

Above the `\[` is a single character, which won't work to copy-paste directly.